# Difference between wxpython and tkinter

Tags: python

Can anybody explain me difference between wxpython and tkinter?
Which one is the best for development?
I want to develop a media player using python.

Comment: Take a look at this url : http://wiki.wxpython.org/Choosing%20wxPython%20over%20Tkinter/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tkinter or wxpython](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888126/tkinter-or-wxpython)

Comment: Nonconstructive? How do you think I -- and most probably a lot of other people -- ended up in here? I tell you what is nonconstructive: Closing questions the answers to which might be helpful. In fact it's worse than nonconstructive: it's *destructive*.

Comment: It appears that wxPython supports screen readers such as JAWS or NVDA where , tkinter does not.  I have an application (see https://github.com/raysmith619/resource_lib/blob/master/README.md) which I need to reprogram to use BOTH tkinter and wxPython to enable screen reading on my windows that don't absolutely need tkinter (e.g. turtle based code)

Answer (score 1):

these are two different widget libraries.

TkInter is built-in, however, as far as I remember, it translates python statements to tcl statements, which might not make it fast. It's also looking like a tcl/tk application on all platforms.

wxpython is NOT built-in, therefore you have to distribute it with your code to all platforms, albeit it 'blends in' a bit more perhaps.

It depends on your needs of course.

I've seen a lot of apps using XULRunner with python, examples are Miro and Songbird, but there are ones which are using gnome/gtk as well I guess.

Depends on which platforms do you want to support...

Comment: I am going to use on Linux platform

Comment: Any of will do, albeit wxPython blends in better... But on linux, I'd simply use GTK directly, perhaps it's just me... wxPython is good to support multiple platforms, GTK is surely built-in because of gnome - https://live.gnome.org/PyGObject, http://developer.gnome.org/gnome-devel-demos/stable/guitar-tuner.py.html.en

Comment: Maybe, just maybe accept the answer then (you're new here, so: if the answer helped you out, there should be an accept button somewhere. It gives the answerer points, I dunno what they're for, but still it seems it's the basis of the game)